# How can I obtain an API-key for my Fusion Tables

Tags: api, rest, google-fusion-tables

Yep, newbie question here, but it's bothering me for some days now, trying to read all the docs on google developer site, but I'm spinning in circles.

I've created a Fusion Table and set the access to 'public' and got an ID.

According to Goolge I should have an API key to access the data from a REST-call. Google suggests:
Go to the Google Developers Console.
Select a project, or create a new one.
In the sidebar on the left, expand APIs & auth. Next, click APIs. In the list of APIs, make sure the status is ON for the Fusion Tables API.
In the sidebar on the left, select Credentials.

I can do that all I've got an API-key, but how does this relates to the Fusion Table I've created? Can I use that API key for

Comment: You are probably looking for the tableid? You can get it in the fusiontable directly: go to File - Share and you can find the table id in the link. The id is the part after 'docid='

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: procedures changed since this post. Your mileage may vary*

- Head to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
- Create a project
- Under Explore other services click "Enable APIs and get credentials like keys"
- Search for Fusion Tables
- Enable Fusion Tables API as a service under APIs & Auth --> APIs
- You probably want the browser key. Grab the API key.

Happy Mapping...

Comment: This isn't quite helpful. There are many differant options. Server key, browser key, iOS key, android key, OAuth Client ID, service account key. I've created a key for each of them and none actually work. Just get a reply back either saying Login Required, Key Expired, or Invalid Key.

Comment: Edited my answer above as the developer's console no longer appears as it did a year ago.

In the past there was only one key, and I can't really speak to the differences. If I had to guess, I'd be using the browser key for everything.

Answer (score 0):

this is really simple API key give the ability to do the most of mysql request type SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE using GET and POST also PUT request , for GET you can use the navigator for that but the most effective way for your case is the use of curl librairie for php or jaira for java ... so you can send post or put request with a simple script.
So, what you can do with fusion table is automating the process of manipulating data and the option to share those data with someone else.

Answer (score -1):

API-keys are not related to specific Fusion Tables, they are related to projects.

You may use the key to request data from any **public** and **downloadable** FusionTable(not only your own Tables ), the key basically is used to identify your project(google-account) .

So when you have problems with requesting data from a public table, check if the table is downloadable too(click on the table-name on top-left->reuse access->allow downloads ).

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work. I've added the download flag but according to google (https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/sample_code) it states that the REST call should look like:     https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/tables/1KxVV0wQXhxhMScSDuqr-0Ebf0YEt4m4xzVplKd4/columns?key={your API key}

If I run it without the API-key I got an 403 error:"code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."

Comment: I get a result when I replace `{your API key}` with my own key

Comment: ...and HOW did you obtain that API key? Basically, that is my main question. Did you get it from Google Developers Console or by some other way?

Comment: It's from the developer console

Comment: Yes, thanks. and it now works! What I still don't understand how the link is between the Console and the fusion tables. For me it seems that they are not directly linked. You can have multiple Projects in your console defined, all with an own API key. You can use any of those API keys for any Fusion table... Doesn't make sense to me, but again, it's a side discussion. Thanks for the help.

Comment: yes, you can use any of those API keys for any fusiontable, but only if you enabled the Fusiontable API in the APis tab...